# call an async function in actix-web middleware

Tags: rust, actix-web

I implemented a actix-web middleware but i'm having issues trying to retrieve a client object from a database pool because that call is an async function:

```
impl <S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for SomeMiddleware<S>
...
fn call(&self, request: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
  if let Some(pool) = request.app_data::web::Data<Pool>>() {
     // this call will not work
     let client = pool.get().await.unwrap();
  }
}
```

How do I get a client object from the pool?

I am using actix-web 4.x and deadpool-postgres.

Comment: There is Actix documentation explains Middleware, also there is example how to use it in `async` context. https://actix.rs/docs/middleware/

Comment: I can't find the example. Sorry. Can you point to it a little closer?

Comment: Could you be more clear on what doesn't "work". Do you mean the code cannot compile? If so what is the error you are getting?

Comment: There's an example here: https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/344bcfce/middleware/middleware/src/read_request_body.rs