# Using async functions within a Actix middleware

Tags: rust, lifetime, actix-web, rust-futures

I'm making a rust API with Actix and Sqlx, and currently working on a JWT middleware, it's mostly done, but I'd like to retrieve the authorized user into my endpoints. That's what the code below is attempting, but I'm running into a lifetime issue.

```rs
fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
    if ApiEnv::skip_auth() {
      return Box::pin(self.service.call(req));
    }

    // Box::pin(self.service.call(req))
    Box::pin(async move {
      let u = {
        let db: &Data<Database> = req.app_data().unwrap();
        let pool = db.pool.clone();
        let headers = req.headers().clone();
        let mut extensions = req.extensions_mut();

        match authorize(pool, headers).await {
          Ok(u) => {
            extensions.insert(u);
            Ok(())
          }, Err(e) => Err(e)
        }
      };
      
      match u {
        Ok(_) => { self.service.call(req).await } 
        Err(e) => Err(e)
      }
    })
  }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/middleware/jwt.rs:98:5
    |
92  |     fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
    |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
98  | /     Box::pin(async move {
99  | |       let u = {
100 | |         let db: &Data<Database> = req.app_data().unwrap();
101 | |         let pool = db.pool.clone();
...   |
116 | |       }
117 | |     })
    | |______^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

I know why this is: I'm using `self.service.call` inside of a `Box::pin`, but how do i fix it?

If I move `self.service.call(req)` outside of the Box::Pin, the `req` value is moved before i call  `let mut extensions = req.extensions_mut();` and `extensions.insert(u)`, so as far as i know, i can't do that either.

There was a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880761/call-an-async-function-in-actix-web-middleware), but all the links either lead to deleted repo's, or [one that calls `self.service.clone()`, despite Service not having a Clone trait](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/344bcfce/middleware/middleware/src/read_request_body.rs)

I'm pretty stuck, and I'm not an expert on Box::pin, so hopefully someone knows if there's a solution to this. Thanks for reading :)

Comment: How is `Self::Future` defined? You can't capture `&self` if it's `Pin<Box<dyn Trait>>` because `dyn Trait` is implicitly `dyn Trait + 'static`, though depending on that you might be able to redefine `Self::Future`, if it doesn't have a lifetime it might not be possible to return something capturing `self`. Do you control the traits definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I figured what was going on, the repo that had self.service.clone() wrapped Service in a Rc<> therefore being able to clone it. I missed it completely.